# How the order of spring filters in Spring Cloud Gateway with Spring SecurityWebFilterChain works?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

Sup, guys.

i'm making a demo project for studying some concepts of spring (cloud-gateway + security), then i was looking for some documents where they explain how is the priority order for each filter, sadly i have only found authorization server + gateway pattern docs.

According to the Spring-cloud-gateway(SCG) [doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#gateway-how-it-works), we have some different filters applied to diferent moments of a single request (like pre/post, and specific for paths GatewayFilterFactory, etc)

but, how is this affected when Spring-Security is in SCG?

does spring [security filter chain](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#explicit-webflux-security-configuration) have priority over the filters that we define in the gateway?

what are the differences between GatewayFilter, OrderedGatewayFilter, GlobalFilter, and WebFilter interfaces?